# how to make iCal4j not fail on parsing errors (like 00001231T000000Z)

Tags: google-calendar-api, ical4j

I am trying to get iCal4j to parse an exported Google .ics calendar file.  Unfortunately the parser chokes on a particular value (00001231T000000Z)  and throws an exception.  My question is how can I get the parser to continue despite the bad data?  I am about to edit the source code but is there not a way to configure it to not fail on a date parse error.

I am using ical4j-1.0.5-SNAPSHOT - which I believe is based on the latest code.

My data contains the following event (which appears to be a recurring one):

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=America/Vancouver:20101206T060000
DTEND;TZID=America/Vancouver:20101206T150000
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20101210T140000Z
DTSTAMP:20121231T143813Z
UID:[deleted]@google.com
CREATED:00001231T000000Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20110102T020817Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:iCal4j chokes on this
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
```

and dies when it tries to parse this date value (which seems to be a nonsense/bad value)

```
CREATED:00001231T000000Z
```

I don't particularly care if the created field is set or is set to a dummy value.  What I care about is the parser continuing and not choking on bad data.

I have tried setting the parsing to relaxed, but somehow this case seems to slip through.

```
        CompatibilityHints.setHintEnabled(
            CompatibilityHints.KEY_RELAXED_PARSING, true);
```

So, how can I make this code more robust to parse errors?  Can I supply my own parser?  Can I get it to skip records that have errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a regression. Relaxed parsing should have covered this case. Just fixed it in both branch and tip (http://ical4j.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/ical4j/ical4j/rev/8c23205afac9).

Comment: The nightlies for 1.0.5 are available here : https://mnode.ci.cloudbees.com/view/ical4j/job/ical4j%20%28ical4j-1.x-maintenance%29/51/org.mnode.ical4j$ical4j/

Answer (score 1):

I copied the CalendarBuilder class and wrapped the property set method with a try/catch as below.  I'm still interested to hear other solutions to this.  I really dislike having to copy an entire class to fix something like this.

```
    public void propertyValue(final String value)
            throws URISyntaxException, ParseException, IOException {

        assertProperty(property);

        try {
            if (property instanceof Escapable) {
                property.setValue(Strings.unescape(value));
            } else {
                property.setValue(value);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.warn("Could not set propety: " + property.getName()
                    + " to " + value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting all these together ?

```
ical4j.unfolding.relaxed=true
ical4j.parsing.relaxed=true
ical4j.validation.relaxed=true
ical4j.compatibility.outlook=true
```

Comment: I just tried these altogether, but it still didn't solve the parse exception error.  Thank you for the suggestion all the same.